# How to set router parameters for IEEE 802.11E QoS Streaming over MultiHop

Tags: networking, qos, opnet

I am working on a multi-hop project in opnet. I am unable to set the router parameters in opnet . The sender and receiver nodes mac addresses and destination addresses are assigned, but how to set them to the router(Currently auto -assigned). Since I'm working on QoS I have enabled HCF Default parameters for nodes and HCF Default QAP for the router.

When I try to stream 8Mbps Video data without router(In this scenario only 1 sender & 1 receiver), the throughput is 6.1Mbps, but in presence of router the throughput is 3.1Mbps..and data drop at router was only 400Kbps, the data drop at sender was 5Mbps.

Could you please help me set the router parameters to get maximum throughput.

Comment: I am using OPNET MODELER 17.5.A

Comment: Can you elaborate more (details with screenshot if possible), which model you are trying to use.